# Increment operator on pointer of array errors?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, dereference, pointer-arithmetic

I'm trying something very simple, well supposed to be simple but it somehow is messing with me...

I am trying to understand the effect of ++ on arrays when treated as pointers and pointers when treated as arrays.

So,

```
int main()
{
    int a[4] = { 1, 4, 7, 9 };
    *a = 3;
    *(a+1) = 4;
    *++a = 4; //compiler error
}
```

**1:** So at `*(a+1)=4` we set a[1]=4; //Happy
But when `*++a = 4;`, I'd expect pointer a to be incremented one since ++ is precedent to * and then * kicks in and we make it equal to 4. But this code just does not work... Why is that?

Another problem:

```
int main()
{

    int* p = (int *)malloc(8);
    *p = 5;
    printf("%d", p[0]);

    *++p = 9; //now this works!
    printf("%d", p[1]); //garbage
    printf("%d", p[0]); //prints 9

}
```

**2:** Now *++p = 9; works fine but it's not really behaving like an array. How are two different? This is just incrementing p, and making it equal to 9. If I print p[0], it now prints 9 and I see that though can't access it via p[0] anymore, *(p-1) shows 5 is still there. So indexing a pointer with [0], where exactly does it point to? What has changed?

Thanks a lot all experts!

Comment: An array is not a pointer. You can't increment it. Also, don't cast the return value of malloc. But these have been discussed hundreds of times already. Why don't you do any research before asking?

Comment: @H2CO3 you don't have to cast malloc's return in C but you do in C++.

Comment: @Adam You don't, because you don't use `malloc()` in `C++` at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens if I increment an array variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334627/what-happens-if-i-increment-an-array-variable)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The array names is not modifiable lvalue so operation ++ is not applied hence `++a` that try to modify `a` is compilation time error (where `a` is array name).

Note `*(a + 1)` and `*a++` are not same, `a + 1` is a valid instruction as it just add `1` but doesn't modify `a` itself, Whereas `++a` (that is equvilent to `a = a + 1`) try to modify a hence error.

Note 'array names' are *not* pointer. Pointers are variable but array names are not. Of-course when you assign array name to a pointer then in most expressions array names decays into  address of first element. e.g.

```
int *p = a;
```

Note `p` points to first element of array (`a[0]`).

Read some [exceptions where array name not decaying into a pointer to first element?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17753057/1673391)

An expression `a[i]` is equivalent to `*(a + i)`, where `a` can be either a pointer or an array name. Hence in your second example `p[i]` is valid expression.

Additionally, `*++p` is valid because because `p` is a pointer (a variable) in second code example.

Comment: This is also the error message compiler is giving. But I'm asking isn't the array name also a pointer, pointing to the first element of an array?

Comment: Thanks, can you also please answer the 2nd question? When we dereference a pointer b, to an array a by [0], it prints b[0] as a[1]. So isn't pointer really behaving like an array?

Comment: @shadowyman It's more like the array is behaving like a pointer. [] is a pointer operation, it's defined on pointers not on arrays.

Comment: Simplified version: Arrays are basically constant, so in using the de/increment operators you're really trying to modify something that cannot be modified. To achieve the desired effect, make a pointer point to the array and increment that.

Answer (score 1):

```
int a[4] = { 1, 4, 7, 9 };
int *pa=a;
```

There is one difference between an array name and a pointer that must be kept in mind. A pointer is a variable, so`pa=a` and `pa++` are legal. But an array name is not a
variable; constructions like `a=pa` and `a++` are illegal

---

```
int* p = (int *)malloc(8);
```

[Don't cast result of malloc()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Use index with pointer

```
p[1]=9; // p[1]==*(p+1)
```

Comment: If we're at it: 1. in standardese parlance, there are no "variables", just objects. So then a pointer isn't a variable either. 2. But if we use the common terminology, then an array is just like any pther normal variable. It's just not assignable.

Comment: H2CO3, so the problem here is trying to modify the array name and behaving like a pointer doesn't make it fully a pointer, correct?

Comment: @H2CO3 You misunderstood Here I was mentioned `array name is not a variable` and pointer is a variable means we can modify it.

Comment: @Gangadhar No, that's not the case. I understood your answer perfectly, and it's incorrect (at best).

Comment: @H2CO3 You may be correct in many cases . sorry in this case i can`t agree with you because this same has quoted in dennis ritchie book.

Comment: @H2CO3: your first remark is incorrect. In standardese parlance, "a _variable_ is introduced by the declaration of an object. The variable's name denotes the object." `[basic]`. That is to say, a variable is any named object introduced by a declaration. You're still right that it's incorrect to say generally that "a pointer is a variable", since for example `static_cast<void*>(NULL)` is an expression whose value is a pointer that is not a variable (because it isn't named and wasn't introduced by a declaration, and for that matter isn't an object since it doesn't have an address).

Comment: However, an array name *is* (the name of) a variable, even though it cannot vary.

Comment: @SteveJessop Right, I retract... I think I have confused the C and the C++ standards. I'll check it.

Comment: @H2CO3: ah, if it is different in C then maybe I'm the one who's looking at the wrong one. As I re-read it, nothing in the question requires C++.